# Merge/union Python Pandas DataFrames with column of unique row IDs and column of lists to DataFrame with all IDs and united, non-repeating lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly new to Pandas, and I therefore don't know if there is a smart an efficient way of doing the following --- e.g., some `merge`-like operation that I don't know. I hope some of you can help.

Say I have two dataframes, where each row contains 1) an ID unique to that dataframe, and 2) a list of items held by that ID. E.g.:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': ['ID1','ID2'], 'items': [['a','b'],['a','b']]}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': ['ID1','ID3'], 'items': [['a','c'],['a','d']]})
```

I would like to combine these dataframes to get the combined information of `df1` and `df2`, so obtain:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': ['ID1','ID2','ID3'], 'items': [['a','b','c'],['a','b'],['a','d']]})
```

Hence, `df3` is `df1`  but 1) where `ID1` holds also the item `c` from `df2` 2) has been appended with the row containing `ID3`.

How may I go about that?

Comment: `'ID2'` repeated in `df3`? Also, does the order of items in the lists matter in the result?

Comment: @MYousefi, my apologies, `ID2` should not repeat: I have corrected it to `ID3`. Item order does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is flatten list before outer `merge` by [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), then reshape by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with remove duplicates and missing values, last aggregate `list`s:

```
df =  (df1.explode('items').merge(df2.explode('items'), on="id", how="outer")
           .melt('id')
           .drop_duplicates(['id','value'])
           .dropna(subset=['value'])
           .groupby('id')['value'].agg(list)
           .reset_index(name='items')
          )
print (df)
    id      items
0  ID1  [a, b, c]
1  ID2     [a, b]
2  ID3     [a, d]
```

Or is possible [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) after `merge`:

```
df =  (df1.merge(df2, on="id", how="outer")
          .set_index('id')
          .stack()
          .explode()
          .groupby(level=0)
          .agg(lambda x: list(set(x)))
          .reset_index(name='items'))
print (df)
    id      items
0  ID1  [c, b, a]
1  ID2     [b, a]
2  ID3     [d, a]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for these suggestions! I will read up on what the individual functions do to understand this fully, and do some time checks to choose a final solution.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most beautiful solution, but maybe it helps:

```
df_final = df1.merge(df2, on="id", how="outer")

df_final["items_x"] = df_final["items_x"].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [])
df_final["items_y"] = df_final["items_y"].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [])

df_final["items"] = (df_final["items_x"] + df_final["items_y"]).apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))

df_final = df_final.drop(["items_x", "items_y"], axis=1)

df_final
```

**Output:**

```
    id      items
0   ID1     [c, a, b]
1   ID2     [a, b]
2   ID3     [d, a]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My sense of aesthetics on this subject may be off, but I like that I understand what's going on! Edit: Both this and the other answer works, so I accept the other as it was first.